# Generic iteration through list

Tags: c#, list, iteration, ienumerable

I've been building an email generator function. It started as a regex function, but quickly moved over to reflection to make it as generic as possible. The idea is to have the email generator function pull in information from a messagedata class. It started as a simple task, as the function only had to change out a few static items, but as the function got more complex and the templates being sent out needed tables of information, then the function I had built was not enough.

I've extended the function to use a foreach loop to run through the template and replace text based on a list from the messageData class. I've been trying to get the list created in messageData to implement it into the emailGenerator function.
I've got:

```
string value = match.Groups["value"].Value;
// Code removed to shorten length
var items = (IEnumerable) value;
```

But it's not gathering the information from the messageData class. I'm thinking that maybe I need to get the value into a list?

Here is the EmailGenerator function:

```
    public class EmailGenerator : IEmailGenerator
    {
        private string mergeTemplate(string template, object obj)
        {
            var operationMatches = operationParser.Matches(template).Cast<Match>().Reverse().ToList();
            foreach (var match in operationMatches)
            {
                string operation = match.Groups["operation"].Value;
                string value = match.Groups["value"].Value;
                var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(value);

                object dataValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);

                if (operation == "endforeach")
                {
                    string foreachToken = "$foreach " + value + "$";
                    var startIndex = template.LastIndexOf(foreachToken, match.Index);
                    var templateBlock = template.Substring(startIndex + foreachToken.Length, match.Index - startIndex - foreachToken.Length);
                    var items = (IEnumerable) value;

                    string blockResult = "";

                    foreach (object item in items)
                    {
                        blockResult += this.mergeTemplate(templateBlock, item);
                    }

                    template = template.Remove(startIndex, match.Index - startIndex).Insert(startIndex, blockResult);
                }
            }
    }
```

And here is the messageData class. It gets the information from a DTO.
** EDIT: Removed unnecessary code.

```
public class messageData : IMailObject
    {
        public List<messageItemData> Items
        {
            get
            {
                var items = new List<messageItemData>();
                foreach (var docDTO in this.recipientDTO.InfoList)
                {
                    items.Add(new messageItemData(docDTO));

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class messageItemData
    {
        // Properties
    }
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that the emailGenerator function is made generic enough to be reusable for other email templates later down the road, gathering the replacement information from the messageData class and the list it contains.

Comment: Can you please read [ask] and [mcve]?

Comment: It's really hard to find what is called when. Could you please reduce unnecessary code and show, what is calling something that does not work?

Comment: @Malior Removed a lot of the code, always unsure what could be useful when asking questions. So, the list<> taken from messageData should be called inside the if (operation == 'endforeach') statement, but unsure if the var items = (IEnumerable) value; is sufficient enough to gather the list and then be usable in the foreach statement below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally found the answer. The code was 99% working. It was as simple as changing `var items = (IEnumerable) value;` for `var items = (IEnumerable) dataValue;`